# Designing a database of Sets

Tags: sql, database-design, nosql

I am trying to figure out how to implement a database containing sets.

The elements can be of three types, simple elementary elements, tuples of those or even sets (and of course tuples of those).

Its starting to feel almost impossible.

My first approach was to use two table of elements that might also contain sets with an ID, Name and a potentail second element to form a tuple:

```
| elemtID | elementName | is_set | element_to_the_right |
  0         a             false    null                    // (a)
  1         a             false    0                       // (a,a)
  2         a             false    1                       // (a,a,a)
  3         A             true     null                    // the set A
  4         B             true     3                       // the set BxA
```

The rows above show how to make the tuple (a,a,a) and also some set A

To specify member ship i'd simple have a kind of adjacency table of the following form:

```
| elemtID | setID |
  0         3      // a <- A
```

where both ID's pointed to elemID's in the first table.

The idea is to models the category of finite sets and i want to be able to have nested sets of arbitrary depth which would require recursive and probably quite advanced queries.

To get away from this I've been looking into alternatives such as mongoDb that has a more flexible schema. but since they don't support joins I'd have to have everything in a single collection and i cant really wrap my head around that.

Now I'm wondering if there might be alternatives to either the design or the database model.
Any comment would be helpful

Regards, Tobias

Comment: I see you tagged the question with [tag:nosql]. Would you still be interested in a relational solution? You won't (easily) avoid recursive queries, though.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic -  Most definatly.  The app i want to build is it self relational.

Comment: Some key-value stores support duplicate keys (berkeleydb, hamsterdb). You can use this to model 1:n relationships, i.e. store the "setId" as key, and multiple "elementId" as record(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

Considerations:

- This is actually quite similar to how a filesystem (without hard links for folders) would be described. SET is analogous to "folder" and ELEMENT to "file". A set can have one or zero super-sets and zero or many sub-sets (recursively). A set can also have zero or many elements.
- No two elements of the same name can belong to the same set (enforced by the composite key {SET_ID, ELEMENT_NAME}).
- All sets are considered "tuples" in a sense that their elements are ordered (that's what the composite key on {SET_ID, ELEMENT_ORDER} is for). The IS_TUPLE simply tells you whether to ignore (FALSE) that order or not (TRUE). In that sense, not only the sets can contain tuples, but vice-verse as well. Other designs are possible where that would be forbidden, but I didn't want to complicate things.
- You may or may not need the ELEMENT table - depends on whether element contains some additional data that should be shareable among multiple sets.

You can get all (direct, non-recursive) elements of the same set / tuple by simple:

```
SELECT * FROM ELEMENT WHERE SET_ID = <whatever>
```

And very similar for sub-sets.

However, getting all elements *recursively* would require either a recursive query (WITH clause, if your DBMS supports it), or successive queries for each set level.

However, beside the "adjacency list" model described above, there are alternatives that may provide different performance characteristics or alleviate the need for recursive queries - take a look at [this presentation by Bill Karwin](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: Hi branko.  I appreciated you taking the time to answer and i think you solution to the tuple issue is Great.  But i cant figurer out how id be able to use sets as elements in other sets using this model.

Comment: @user25470 See the self-referencing FK in SET? Every sub-set will have PARENT_SET_ID equal to SET_ID of the super-set. Root set(s) will have NULL in PARENT_SET_ID. This is a standard "adjacency list" way of representing hierarchical data - you'll find very similar example in the presentation I linked.

Comment: In all honesty i cant really say that i like this scheme very much, it makes element, which is supposed to be the general quantity, in to the specific and then set in to the general. But it does what i asked for and i do appreciate you taking your time. It might very well be that there is no way to contain "all" sets in a finite set of relations, seeing that these them self are sets.